# How to add to the minimum values from aggregate the simple values from another column in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

In the following Pandas DataFrame, I would like to make an aggregate computation (minimum value), and at the same time simply add a value that is in another column. I am able to solve this, but I suspect that there is a simpler solution inside `gb.agg`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'], 'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'], 'C' : np.random.randn(8), 'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
```

This may give something like the following DataFrame:

```
  A   B    C     D
0 foo one 0.229 0.902
1 bar one 0.594 1.917
2 foo two -0.913 2.444
3 bar three -0.628 -0.902
4 foo two -0.223 -1.063
5 bar two -0.223 0.311
6 foo one -0.592 0.964
7 foo three 0.869 0.817
```

How to add D just because it is in the same row as the min. C in an aggregate?

In more detail, for both groups 'foo' and 'bar' the minimum value is taken for C. My aim is that it takes at the same time the data in the corresponding rows for column D. Note what I *not* want is `df.groupby('A').min()`, which would return for every column the minimum value of a category.

A possible solution is:

```
ndf = df.groupby('A').agg({'C': {'Cmin': np.min}}).reset_index()
ndf.columns = ['A', 'C']
pd.merge(ndf, df.loc[:,['A','C','D']], how='left', on=['A','C'])
```

Which results in:

```
   A   C     D
0 bar -0.628 -0.902
1 foo -0.913 2.444
```

But I wondered if there is something more elegant in **Python 3**, that can directly be used in the groupby.agg for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. We use `idxmin` to retrieve in the index value of the column minimums by group, then use this index via `iloc`. Finally, you can drop any unwanted column(s).

```
df.iloc[df.groupby('A')['C'].agg(pd.Series.idxmin)].drop('B', 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was searching for!